# How one can keep two young table middle of the page

Tags: formatting

```
\begin{Young}
&&&&\cr
\cr
\end{Young}


\begin{Young} 
&&\cr
&&\cr
\end{Young}
```

Those are two young tables. Please help me to keep those tables in the same line middle of the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a fill compilable code?

Comment: What is Young table?

Comment: Maybe by removing the empty lines, but without having a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) this is just a guess.

Comment: @Sigur: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau

Comment: If in a LaTeX environment a `\cr` is used, something is wrong, actually. I don't know a package, that provides the `Young` environment. The [tag:latex3] tag is wrong, most likely

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: The `Young` environment is apparently defined in the [`young` package](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/jknappen/young.sty)

Comment: @leandriis: `texdoc`  does not report `young.sty`, that's why I did not find it

Comment: @user454229: You seem to be using the `Young` package from 1992. Why not switch to a newer package like [`ytableau`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ytableau) which offers a somehow similar syntax, a lot more options for customization and prints two young tables in the same line if both environments are not separated by blank lines?

Comment: @Sigur didn't you read my thesis:(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sorry... it would be a pleasure to take a look. Is it online? :-)

Comment: @Sigur unfortunately IBM golfball typewriters didn't produce eprint versions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, just for fun, you could consider a new edition of it!!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome user454229, remember to include a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of code so others can reproduce your problem and find a solution.

I used the `ytableau` package to produce this result, as suggested in the comments the other package is very old. You could also do this with TiKz but would be more complicated.

To have the captions right I used the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package.
The `minipage` idea is fairly common and works most of the time. See how `.48\textwidth` should correspond to **48%** of the total text width of the page, thus using only half of it.

I hope what you were looking for is something like this:

[image: young tables side by side]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{.48\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Young a}
\centering
    \ytableausetup{centertableaux}
    \begin{ytableau}
    a & d & f \\
    b & e & g \\
    c
    \end{ytableau}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.48\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Young b}
\centering
    \ytableausetup{centertableaux}
    \begin{ytableau}
    a & d & f \\
    b & e & g \\
    c
    \end{ytableau}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```